# I want to make a script to display google ads on WordPress site after the user touch the screen

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I want to make a script to display google ads on a WordPress site after the user touch the screen

this is the code I've made so far

```
 <script>
    var d ="ontouchstart";
    
    if (d === false ) {
        return false;
    }
    
    if (d === true) {
        $.getScript("https://pagead2.googlesyation.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js");
    }
    </script>
```

any help pls

by the way I just start with java 2days ago so I don't know a lot